# Please help me choosing: Django, Drupal, PHP framework, JSP

Tags: php, django, drupal, jsp

I can't decide what web technology is good for me.
I need something to make quite simple web apps, with single relational database, authentication, social features. Imagine for example a "Desktop wallpapers sharing community".

These are my personal pro/cons of the various technologies I tried (everything is related to MY experience):

**DRUPAL**

- (+) large community
- (+) cheap hosting
- (+) great modules available
- (+) content types, views, SEO
- (-) not a real framework (can't imagine how to make simple queries/operations)
- (-) templating is so non-natural to me
- (-) i hate working with those "blocks"
- (-) difficult to modify/create modules
- (-) don't like php

**DJANGO**

- (+) i enjoy working with python
- (+) very flexible with templating (in love with inheritance)
- (+) very good built-in ORM that suits my needs
- (+) great documentation and good community resources
- (+) great security features
- (+) clean url system
- (-) not so cheap hosting
- (-) tricky with static files, external resources
- (-) i'm not too good at it, yet (making a good blog requires some days of work to me)
- haven't tried to deploy/publish a django website. don't know how it is difficult.

**PHP FRAMEWORKS** (example: CodeIgniter/Kohana)

- (+) tons of cheap hosting services
- (+) fast development (great results with less code)
- (+) huge amount of ready-to-use libraries
- (-) not great documentation
- (-) don't like php
- (-) i find the django ORM by far superior
- (-) security?!

**JSP**

- (+) i've been working with java for years
- (+) persistence API
- (-) is java dying?
- (-) expensive hosting
- (-) "heavy" workflow for basic tasks
- (-) old url scheme organization

I'd like to read your opinions. I have to find a technology I can use for all of my web projects (including "normal" websites with content editing features, for my clients).
I strongly would like to use only one of them, for everything. But I really can't decide which is worth to study in depth, in order to get a job in the future too!

Thank you.

Comment: Do hosting expenses really THAT matter?

Comment: If you want an opinion just search this site, there's a question like this every week.

Comment: Please help me choose between salad, vodka, soufflé and sardines.

Comment: I was specifying what pros/cons the salad, vodka, soufflè and sardines I have experienced. I'm so sad the question's been closed.

Comment: This is always a "dangerous" question, but +1 for your list and research.